# How to compile the LIBVLC example code on windows using gcc

Tags: c, vlc, libvlc

I want to build the libvlc example (https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial) so i downloaded the sources and also copied libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll (from my vlc installation) into the current directory. Then i try to compile it by issuing

```
gcc example.c -o example -I./include -L./lib -L./ -llibvlc
```

but get the error

```
example.c:3:22: fatal error: vlc/vlc.h: No such file or directory
  #include <vlc/vlc.h>
                      ^
```

I hope this is enough information, i controlled all paths and files twice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's in `./include`?

Comment: The folder include from the vlc source https://github.com/videolan/vlc

Comment: What do you think about it? Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need **vlc sdk**, not just files from vlc source code ;
2. you need dll files for your already compiled application, but for build you need .lib files - also part of sdk;
3. for this you need to build them - for this step refer to https://medium.com/@tobias.strg/compiling-vlc-3-x-in-2020-a390c6a73c24;
4. no doubt you can use some nigthly builds of vlc (check for zip files with "debug" suffix) https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc-3.0/nightly-win64/20220420-0220;
5. after you got sdk pack for your platform you can compile - pointing to headers files from **sdk**, and linking with libs from **sdk**;